# Cross site 500 error on question pages

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, questions, 500-server-error

When I goto https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ and click on any of the links for a question, I get the [oops page](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/441/is-it-appropriate-to-answer-the-question-we-think-the-poster-is-asking-in-low-qu).  So, per the page's request, I'm reporting it here.

It's not just that question.  It's every question on that site, and also on many other sites.

Comment: Purging the comments here since we've established that it's happening on all sites sporadically for different users.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/714494616821702656

Comment: This was our fault. We noticed that our error pages got appreciably fewer views than everything else, and asked engineering to break everything in order to fix that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was a bug in pathing that should never be allowed to bring down question pages anyway - a fix has been deployed and I'll be preventing that code from causing such drastic issues ever again in my next commit.

Comment: By 'ever again', he means 'ever, ever, ever, **ever ever** ***ever*** again. Finality is this man's specialty.

Comment: Admit it Nick, you missed hitting the rep cap here on MSE. :-D

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a post-mortem question (haven't had one of those in a while ;)) but why didn't this error show up in dev?

Comment: @hichris123 details in the post-mortem at https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/141859797844/partial-outage-postmortem-march-28th-2016

Answer (score 13):

According to the @StackStatus Twitter, a new build is being rolled out that corrects this issue:

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/714495272127082496

[image]

Comment: It's usually better to let the developers and/or community managers comment on what happened (given they're the ones that fix it...)

Comment: @Quill I agree.  Which is why I only posted from an official source and didn't just write an answer like, "It seems to be fixed now".